# Does req.abort() always trigger error event in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, events, https, error-handling

Like the title says... 
I use the HTTPS module for nodejs and when making requests I set timeout and attach an error listener.

```
    req.setTimeout(6000, function(){
        // mark_completed(true);
        this.abort();
    })
    .on('error', function (e){
        if (!this.aborted){
            // mark_completed(true);
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

In both scenarios I want to execute a function to mark my request as completed.

Is it safe to assume that on error will always be triggered after after the timeout, so that I can place my function exclusively inside the on error event?

Comment: I have seen similar code drifting around the internets, claiming `abort()` fires `error`, but it does not appear to be true. The docs say `abort()` triggers `abort` event, it doesn't say if `error` should be fired. My own snippets did not trigger the error event, only abort event.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps different build versions handle it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Since Node.js v13.14.0, `req.abort()` on `http.ClientRequest` instances has been deprecated in favor of `req.destroy()`. The docs for that method are rather straightforward in regard to error emitting:

> Destroy the request. Optionally emit an 'error' event, and emit a 'close' event. Calling this will cause remaining data in the response to be dropped and the socket to be destroyed.
>
> —[Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestdestroyerror)

This is how it behaves:

```js
// Closes the response stream, does not emit the "error" event
// because no "reason" was provided.
// Emits the "close" event.
req.destroy()

// Closes the response stream, emits the "error" event with
// "custom-error" as the reason. Emits the "close" event.
req.destroy('custom-error')
```

Only if the underlying stream was created with the `emitClose: false` option, calling `req.destroy()` won't emit the "close" event. In all the other cases, it will.